# Django Pivot Table Creation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Good Afternoon,

I am working on a Django App. I have created a model like below.

[image: Django Model]

From that model I would like to create a view displaying such a table as below:

[image: Table in template html]

As you can see I would like to create rows per country name in the model database and I would like to give counts per specification.

I could create the table with the country names by adding a meta class to the model for the country field and then loop it with template injection. To do that I also created a view as below:

```
def sum(request):
country_list_unique = Project.objects.order_by().values('country_ordering').distinct()
return render(request, 'project/project_sum.html', {'sumup':country_list_unique})
```

However, I don't have much of an idea how can I count the different specifications per country in views.py and how to inject them into html with Django.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You may want to include the actual code (particularly the fields) of the model(s) containing the data you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the data using https://github.com/martsberger/django-pivot